# Flutter Dropdown: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use a dropdown list in flutter and values of dropdown are supposed to add by HTTP request.

Here is the code for HTTP.

```
Future<String> getData() async {
    try{ 
    var deviceid = '123';
      var dtgUid = '123';

      var body = { "uid" : dtgUid, "deviceid": deviceid};

       var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(body)).timeout(Duration(seconds: 15),
            onTimeout: (){
                    //  throw Exception();
              _showSnackBar(context,'Some issue with connectivity. Can not connect to server.',Colors.redAccent);
                      //or you can also
              return null;
            });

     if(response. statusCode == 200){
        final datafromdb = getNewsTypeFromJson(response.body);
        setState(() {
          _inProcess = false;
                        if(datafromdb.content.length == null){
                          count = 0;
                        }else{
                          count = datafromdb.content.length;
                        }

                         if(datafromdb.content.length > 0 && datafromdb.content[0].tagname != 'Empty'){
                        for (var i in datafromdb.content) {
                          print(i.tagname);
                          data.add(i.tagname);
                        }  
                      }else{
                        nodata = 'No Record Found';
                        _showSnackBar(context,nodata,Colors.redAccent);
                      }

        });
     }
       }catch(e){
       print("Exception Caught: $e");
    }


    }
```

Here is the JSONParse.

```
import 'dart:convert';

GetNewsType getNewsTypeFromJson(String str) => GetNewsType.fromJson(json.decode(str));

class GetNewsType {
    GetNewsType({
        this.content,
        this.success,
    });

    List<Content> content;
    bool success;

    factory GetNewsType.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GetNewsType(
        content: List<Content>.from(json["content"].map((x) => Content.fromJson(x))),
        success: json["success"],
    );

}

class Content {
    Content({
        this.tagname,
    });

    String tagname;

    factory Content.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Content(
       // tagname: json["tagname"],
        tagname: json == null ? 'Empty' : json["tagname"]
    );
}
```

Here is the code for dropdown.

```
DropdownButton(
                        items: data.map((item) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: Text(item['tagname']),
                            value: item['tagname'].toString(),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (newVal) {
                          setState(() {
                            _mySelection = newVal;
                          });
                        },
                        value: _mySelection,
                      ),
```

When I run the app it is giving below error. Which I don't understand.

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

Comment: use return new DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: new Text(item.tagname),
                            value: item.tagname,
                          );

Comment: Thanks. I did that and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't executed the code but the error message and this line in code `item['tagname']` appears like `List<String>` is being accessed with a `key` like a `map` .
Since in the `.map()` you have the individual `Content` object use the `.` like `item.tagname`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What exactly i need to do to fix the issue. Sorry as i am having quite less knowledge.

Comment: The places where `item['tagname']` is used, change to `item.tagname`

Answer (score 0):

Class 'String' has no instance getter 'tagname'.
Receiver: ""
Tried calling: tagname